# How to configure Visual Studio Code for C++ on Windows?

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I face problem with configuring *launch.json* file on my Windows and it shows error message

> Debug adapter process has terminated unexpectedly.

I have set up "MinGW" and configured g++ compiler, and now Visual Studio Code compiles correctly. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, it creates *a.exe* file in project folder.

My *launch.json* file:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C++ Launch (Windows)",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/a.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false
        },
        {
            "name": "C++ Attach (Windows)",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command.pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

My *task.json* file:

```json
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "g++",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "always",
    "args": ["-std=c++11","-g", "main.cpp"]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be wrong, but I suppose you need to compile your `.c/.cpp` file with microsoft `cl.exe` compiler (not by gcc) to use microsoft debugger on it. To setup paths for `cl`, call the `vcvarsall.bat` with parameter `x86` or `x64` (depends on what you need) and then cast `cl` to your `source file`. By the way check this article (the part with json configuration exactly) to ensure, where you did wrong https://www.40tude.fr/blog/how-to-compile-cpp-code-with-vscode-cl/

Comment: there's nothing wrong with debugging non-MS files in VS code because it's just an editor and will call the corresponding debugger (gdb, lldb, whatever...) https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw